# How can I change the gap between a plot's frame and its legends?

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

How can I change the gap (marked by the double arrow below) between a frame and a plot legend?

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x + y^2], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Right]]
```

[image]

I tried to use `Placed`, but the result was same as `Placed -> {Automatic, Right}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the margins from around the legend  by setting [`LegendMargins`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendMargins.html) to 0, and use the form $\{\{e_x, e_y\},\{l_x,l_y\}\}$ for *pos* in `Placed[legend, pos]`.

From [`Legended >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html)

[image]

For example, setting $l_x = .1$  we get:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x + y^2], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMargins -> 0] , 
     {{1, .5}, {0.1, .5}}]]
```

[image]